# Hide success and error messages on form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have one subscription form with ajax. The problem is that `success` and `error` messages are always on the page. Why they are on the page and how to hide them until form is submitted?

This is my js function

```
$(document).ready(function(){

(function($) {
    "use strict";

// validate subscribeForm form
$(function() {
    $('#subscribeForm').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Please enter your name?",
                minlength: "Your name must consist of at least 4 characters"
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please enter your email address"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                type:"POST",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                url:"subscribe.php",
                success: function() {
                    $('#subscribeForm :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#subscribeForm').fadeTo( "slow", 0.15, function() {
                        $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $(this).find('label').css('cursor','default');
                        $('#sub_success').fadeIn();
                    });
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('#subscribeForm').fadeTo( "slow", 0.15, function() {
                        $('#sub_error').fadeIn();
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    })
})      
})(jQuery)
})
```

And this is the form

```
<div class="footer-newsletter row footer-widget right-box">
    <h3 class="footer-title">newsletter sign up</h3>
        <form class="form-inline newsletter-form" id="subscribeForm" method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="sub_submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <div id="sub_success">You subscribe succesfully!</div>
        <div id="sub_error">Opps! There is something wrong. Please try again</div>                      
</div>
```

So `sub_success` and `sub_error` are always on the page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this following things in your code:-

```
<div id="sub_success" style="display:none">You subscribe succesfully!</div>
<div id="sub_error" style="display:none">Opps! There is something wrong. Please try again</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this type alert it will gone in 3sec

`$('#success_message').fadeIn(1000).html("<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert' style='font-size: 15px;'>Soory some there is some error,please enter again data...</div>").fadeOut(3000);`

Answer (score 1):

Just add `.hide` on `document.ready` for both elements as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.sub_success,.sub_error').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just write a css

```
#sub_success, #sub_error {display:none}
```

then with jquery you can just show and hide by using

```
$("#sub_success").show();
$("#sub_error").hide();
```